# Laravel - @json error - expression expected

Tags: javascript, php, json, laravel-7

I always get this error trying to pass a variable from PHP code to javascript.

> Expression expected

That's my code in Laravel 7.0 :

```
<script> let variable = @json($array); </script>
```

The code is still working. So I can use the variable $array in my javascript code. But it's always showing the error. Does anyone know how to fix this ?

Comment: Look at the source code in the browser to see what it looks like. I'm not sure if you'll need to quote the json.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use for example:

```
<script>
    let variable = {!! json_encode($array) !!};
</script>`
```

Reference: https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/blade#displaying-data

Or if it still shows error then you can try:

```
<script>
    let variable = [].concat(@json($array));
</script>
```

Comment: @NKol - have you tried my second suggestion on this issue? It does not look like an error though, it is more like a false warning of the IDE in the first place (PHPStorm). Is your editor updated?

Comment: thanks for your help. I am using PHPStorm and I updated it to the newest version. Now the error is gone. I guess I just had an outdated version of PHPStorm.